# $resource access to the promise angularJs ng-resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Is there any way to access the promise of $resource since it warps my data into an object "m" and i cant access to that m so i cant get my data attributes is there any solution for this ?

```
[m, $promise: d, $resolved: true]
```

the m contains all my data but i cant access any of my data attributes to work my way with them.

here is my resource:

```
function getBank(id){
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/bank/:id').query({id : id}).$promise.then(function(user){
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

now the console.log give me this : `[m, $promise: d, $resolved: true]`
which warps my data is there anyway to access that 'm' ?

Comment: unclear what you are asking.. add more explanation + code..

Comment: i updated my question hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

well i will use $http since it dose not warp the promise given back which arrange my case thank you all here is how i changed my service:

```
angular.module('myApp.profile').factory('Bank',Bank);
```

Bank.$inject = ['$resource','$http'];
function Bank($resource,$http){

```
var service =  {};
service.getBank = getBank;
return service;

/*function getBank(id){
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/bank/:id').query({id : id}).$promise.then(function(user){
        console.log(user);
    });
}*/
function getBank(id, callback){
    var response ;
    return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/bank/'+id).then(function(bank){
        response = {success : true, bank : bank};
        callback(response);
    },function(error){
        response = {success : false, message : "Error retreiving Bank data"};
        callback(response);
    });

}
```

}

controller call :

```
Bank.getBank($rootScope.loggedUser._id,function(response){
    if(response.success){
        $scope.bank = response.bank;
        console.log(response.bank.data[0]._id);
    }else{
        console.log(response.message);
    }
});
```

and it should the trick :)

Answer (score -1):

You don`t need to use $promise.

Seems you don`t understand how to use ngResource..

Try to wrote factory firstly:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .factory('User', User);

User.$inject = ["$resource"];
function User($resource){
    return {
      getBank: $resource('http://localhost:3000/bank/:id', {id: '@id'}),
  }
};
})();
```

and then in controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('BankController', BankController);

BankController.$inject = ["$scope", "User"];
function BankController($scope, User){
    User.getBank.get({id:1}, function(item){
     console.log(item);
    },function(err){
      $scope.error=true;
    });
  }
}
})();
```

Comment: **Seems you don't understand how to use ngResource** (he is using it in correct way).. `$promise` is required to have promise chain... the way you are using is callback functions..

Comment: i know how to use ngResource my problem is in the way ngResource returns the promise